# Symfony3 500 error on production

Tags: php, server, production, symfony

I am having troubles with deploying a Symfony3 application. I only run a simple REST API on it but I keep getting a 500.

My server runs on Ubuntu and I have Apache running on it. I also run Floxor on a subdomain but I don't think that it should be a problem.

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I had no troubles while finishing it. Everything worked fine except that I had to adapt on the Symfony3 commands, the guide is written with Symfony2 commands (I guess).

It's strange that everything works locally. I've also tried to change the

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

but that did not really work.

Another thing is that the logs of Symfony did not log anything. I also can make sure that the right access is granted to the folder (see [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)). I also checked the log of my apache but I did not see any strange things.

Any idea's?

EDIT:
To provide more information, I used Floxor to tell that this subdomain (which I am using for the api) that the root folder is the /web folder of the Symfony application.

Comment: Try navigating to the `app_dev.php` front controller. If you get a forbidden error, just add your ip address to the line that starts with `!(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in the above mentioned file. (don't forget to remove it later if you don't have a static ip address to work with).

Comment: did You run cache:clear on prod server?

Comment: I did @RafalKozlowski